# Как сделать чекбокс для активации группы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатие на основной чекбокс активировались все как это сделать

Этот скрипт не отмечает все чекбоксы после нажатия на главный

сам скрипт:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#checkbox').click(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#controls input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        $('#controls input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

чекбоксы которые должны активироваться:

```
<p id="controls">
  @foreach($othet as $oth)
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox"   name="id[]" value="{{$oth->id}}"></th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</p>
```

главный чекбокс:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```

Comment: Ну а у данного кода какая проблема? За исключением что у вас тег `<p>` вообще неясно каким боком залез в структуру таблицы.

Comment: Если поможет я брал за основу код с сайта https://snipp.ru/jquery/checkbox-jquery . А таблица просто в моем случае

Comment: Я не вижу здесь полной разметки, но оборачивать ряды таблицы в тег `<p>` - __невалидно__ и браузер скорее всего игнорирует наличие тега `<p>`. Поэтому селектор `$('#controls input:checkbox')` не выбирает __ничего__.

Comment: Работает же https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/bqaL06je/

Comment: Тогда тем более непонятно в чем проблема топикстартера? Забыл подключить jquery?

Comment: Нет jquery подключен ,а может быть это из за foreach??

Comment: Консоль разработчика что показывает?

Comment: Давайте готовый html

Comment: В консоли ошибок нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев на код, складывается пример, что "главный чекбокс" должен у всех чекбоксов в `#controls` менять статус выбора..

Если это так, то вот:

```js
let controlsInput = $('#controls').find('input[type="checkbox"]');

$('#checkbox').on('click', function(){
  let thisStatus = $(this).prop('checked');
  
  controlsInput.prop('checked', thisStatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="controls">
  <input type="checkbox" checked><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked><br>
  <input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked><br>
  <input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="checkbox"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
</div>

<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <label for="checkbox">Выбрать все</label>
```